# SQLite Insert is Performed but Record isn't in DB

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am trying to insert records into an SQLite Database on Android to persist high scores data for a game I am making in Unity.
All select statements are already set up and functional, and this functionality works when I try it on the same DB in Windows. However in Android, logs tell me that rows were inserted into my DB; but when I check the DB they aren't there.

The connection string for my DB is URI=file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tinyproductions.satellitescramble/files/GameRepo.s3db.
I've tried using both this string through Application.persistentDataPath, and the same way I am accessing through Windows with Application.dataPath on the off chance that the prior is used only to create the db from my apk.

I've also tried using all of IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() and IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar() to run this command.

```cs
String GetConnection() {
        String conn, path = "";
        switch (Application.platform) {
            case RuntimePlatform.Android:
                { 
                    path = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath;
                    conn = Path.Combine(path, "GameRepo.s3db");
                    if (!File.Exists(conn)) {

                        WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/GameRepo.s3db");
                        try
                        {
                            while (!load.isDone)
                            {
                                if (timer > loadTimeout)
                                {
                                    throw new FileLoadException("The connection original database timed out", load.url);
                                }
                                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                            }

                            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameRepo.s3db", load.bytes);
                        }
                        catch (FileLoadException e) {
                            Debug.LogError(e.Message + ":FILE:" + e.FileName);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer:
                {
                    path = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Raw";
                    conn = Path.Combine(path, "GameRepo.s3db");
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    path = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";
                    conn = Path.Combine(path, "GameRepo.s3db");
                    break;
                }
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

```
c#
public void inputScore(string username, long score)
    {
        conn = GetConnection();
        Debug.Log(conn);
        dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(conn);
        dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
        IDbCommand insert = dbconn.CreateCommand();
        string insertStatement = $"INSERT INTO HighScores(PlayerName, Score) VALUES(\"{username}\",{score});";
        insert.CommandText = insertStatement;
        var rows = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Debug.Log("Rows changed: " + rows);
        insert.Dispose();
        dbconn.Close();
    }
```

My expectation is that when I run the insert, it will be committed to an already existing table named HighScores at Android/data/com.tinyproductions.satellitescramble/files/GameRepo.s3db, and that I can later run select on this table to get it back. No exceptions are being printed by ADB, and Debug.Log() is telling me that a row has been affected in the DB, but the table remains empty on Android.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Could it be a permissions issue? Also try `using(var conn = ...)` and `using(var cmd = ...)` blocks to to make sure `Dispose` and `Close` are called if there's an exception.

Comment: Doubt it's a permissions issue, if it were write permissions I would get an exception for that, as for read permissions I've got other select statements running on that DB that work fine

Comment: How are you checking the database to see if the new row is present?

Comment: I downloaded an SQLite DBMS on my phone, I've been checking the DB through that